# How to merge two volume when it show two time in disk management, without data loss?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, partitioning, disk-management

I want to know how to merge two-volumes which appears two times in disk management,  I have Local Disk D which is showing two times in disk management, I want to merge it. Help Please.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The two `D` partitions on Disk 0 are one spanned (dynamic) volume.

You don't have two `D` partitions, but only one, as you can see in the upper
list, where disk `D` is only mentioned once as `Dynamic`.

So the two partitions are already merged. To make them into one larger sequential
partition, you would need to:

- Backup all the data on `D`
- Delete disk `D` so both partitions become unallocated space
- Move `C` left to the beginning of the disk so the unallocated space
  from the first `D` follows it (rather than being before it)
- Recreate one partition from the unified unallocated space
- Format the partition and give it the letter `D`
- Restore the saved data.

This would need to be done while booting  from a
[third-party partition editor](https://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-partition-management-software.htm),
and the smallest error can also destroy `C`.

Are you very sure you want to do this?

Comment: Thanks for your useful information, but I can't take any risk, I don't want to use any third party softwares, because I already deleted all of my data under volume E:

Comment: There is no connection - I'm just informing here that the `C` disk cannot be moved while Windows is booted, so it needs to be from a partition manager that is not included in Windows. Personally, I'm also of the opinion that you shouldn't do the above procedure that I described, as it is too dangerous.